# Screen scraping advice: Interactive graph

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have recently followed some tutorials on how to use BeautifulSoup with Python and have learnt how to simply scrape text and urls from webpages. I am now trying to scrape data from the following link,

http://www.study.cam.ac.uk/undergraduate/apply/statistics/

There is an interactive graph generator at the bottom of the page and I would like to scrape all the data from it without having to spend many hours tediously handwriting down the values from all the possible graphs generated. I have tried to use my measly beginner techniques but it is not obvious to me where in the HTML the graph data is coming from - in addition the HTML seems to be dynamic depending on where my mouse is on the screen.

The Question: Is it possible to scrape this data using these tools and if so how?

Comment: use the web developer console to peek at the response from http://www.study.cam.ac.uk/undergraduate/apply/statistics/data.php it has all the data in the charts nice and clean and the page just plots that ajax-fed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using browser developer tools, you can see that when you click on `Show Graph` button there is a `POST` request going to http://www.study.cam.ac.uk/undergraduate/apply/statistics/data.php. The result is a `JSON` object containing all of the data needed to build a graph.

Simulate this request in Python, for example, with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module:

```
import requests

URL = "http://www.study.cam.ac.uk/undergraduate/apply/statistics/data.php"
HEADERS = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

data = {
    'when': 'year',
    'year': 2014,
    'applications': 'on',
    'offers': 'on',
    'acceptances': 'on',
    'groupby': 'college',
    'for-5-years-what': 'university'
}

response = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers=HEADERS)
print response.json()
```

No need for `BeautifulSoup` here. At least, from what I've understood from your question.

Comment: Thanks very much this was perfect. Two more little questions: How did you know what the dictionary keys were in data?: Relatively speaking, how useful is understanding html code to this endeavor of web scraping? Cheers

Comment: @PhilArathoon I've just used chrome developer tools to see the request. Then, I inspected it and saw the request parameters. Then, I've just repeated the request in Python.

Comment: @PhilArathoon since you said that this worked perfectly, you should accept this answer . At least give it +1!

Comment: I do not have the reputation yet to give it a +1. Alas I will give it in spirit. Now that you mention it I have just discovered the accept answer feature. Thankyou.