# Scraping Data From Interactive Map

Tags: python, svg, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the voter registration data underlying this map:

http://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2012/08/28/registration-figures-show-massachusetts-voters-continue-abandon-two-major-political-parties/p0zW7Snj9R07DK913P36kM/igraphic.html?p1=Article_Graphic

As you hover over each town, both the total and the by-party figures in the box below change. I would like to record the name of each town and registration counts by party. Any suggestions about how to do this would be very helpful. I've done some scraping in the past but not with anything interactive like this and my first few attempts with various python packages haven't worked.

(Unfortunately, the sources link at the bottom is not useful because it just links to the Secretary of State's main page and the original report with data is no longer available)

Comment: Hi, Can I look at your code to help you out please

Comment: StackOverflow is for _specific_ programming questions, not a general forum for "how do I learn to program?" topics. Sorry.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Sorry you feel that way. I felt the question was similar in spirit to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194541/screen-scraping-advice-interactive-graph) which got a positive resolution but is no longer useful because the underlying page has changed.

Comment: @therealprashant I've got two lines to use urllib.request to pull down the static html, but none of the map data is there.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist you can still point him to some techs to do it.

Comment: @jfeigenbaum Downloading the source is not enough here. I found that the data is hardcoded but otherwise he would have needed a scraper with a JS engine to do what he wants. Or eventually run some JS directly on the page.

Comment: @Maresh Perfect. Accepted your solution below. I had been hunting around the XHR and HTML tabs in developer tools, but foolishly skipped the JS tab. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to be that one down/close voter who actually explains the position instead of doing a drive-by. Glad you got an answer. The question is still off-topic. (It has 3 close votes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to build an app to scrape this, I just looked at the source of the page for 5 min, check this out:

http://www.bostonglobe.com/r/Boston/2011-2020/WebGraphics/Metro/BostonGlobe.com/2012/08/voter/voter-regs.js

**Otherwise**

You need to have a technology that has a javascript engine, like phantomjs or firefox/chrome drivers.

If you want to stick to python, Selenium webdriver is the way to go.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/